# error : ORA-01858: a non-numeric character was found where a numeric was expected

Tags: java, oracle10g, sqlexception

When i execute my prepared statement i am getting the `ORA-01858: a non-numeric character was found where a numeric was expected`. When i searched through some forums, they say it is because of the date datatype. My prepared statement is

```
insert  into OPRS_ZONES(
  ZONE_ID,
  ZONE_CODE,
  ZONE_NAME,
  PLACE_ID,
  CORP_ID,
  CREATED_BY,
  CREATED_DATE,
  MODIFIED_BY,
  MODIFIED_DATE) 
values(?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)
```

The values i am trying to insert are

```
03.0, 
'FLORIDA', 
'FLORIDA', 
05231.0, 
01.0, 
01.0, 
TO_DATE('19102012130639','DDMMYYYYHH24MISS'), 
NULL, 
NULL
```

Table Definition

```
CREATE TABLE OPRS_ZONES ( 
  ZONE_ID NUMERIC(20,0) , 
  ZONE_CODE VARCHAR2(16) , 
  ZONE_NAME VARCHAR2(255) , 
  PLACE_ID NUMERIC(20,0) , 
  CORP_ID NUMERIC(20,0) , 
  CREATED_BY NUMERIC(20,0) , 
  CREATED_DATE DATE , 
  MODIFIED_BY NUMERIC(20,0) , 
  MODIFIED_DATE DATE );
```

The code where i am populating the values for prepared statement,

```
public int executePreparedStatement(String query, List myCollection, int colLength, String tableName) throws DBException,SQLException {

        int rowsAffected    = 0; 
        int [] noOfRowsExecuted = null;
        try{
            conn.setAutoCommit(false);
            if(query != null){  
                ps = conn.prepareStatement(query);
                for (int i = 0; i < myCollection.size(); i++) {
                    logger.info("@@mycollcetion -- "+myCollection.get(i));
                    List list = (List) myCollection.get(i);
                    int count = 1;
                    for (int j = 0; j < list.size(); j++) {
                        ps.setObject(count, list.get(j));
                        count++;
                    }
                    ps.execute();
                    logger.info("@@ noOfRowsExecuted == "+noOfRowsExecuted);
                }
            }
        }catch(Exception e){
            logger.error("Error in the execution of Prepared Statement: \n" + query + "\nData : " + listData, e);
            rowsAffected    = Utility.getErrorCode(e);
            throw new DBException(e);
        }finally{ 
            try {
                if (ps != null) {
                    ps.close();
                    ps = null;
                }
            } catch (Exception e) {
            }
            rowsAffected    = 0; 
            noOfRowsExecuted = null;
        }
        return rowsAffected;        
    }
```

The `list myCollection` contains the `values`. The variabele `query` is the `prepared statement` 
This prepared statement when replaced with values works fine in SQLDEVELOPER, but when i run through my java program i'm getting error. Is this really problem with date format ? if so why is it working fine in SQLDEVELOPER ?

Please help,

Thanks

Comment: Post the `CREATE TABLE` statement for `OPRS_ZONES`

Comment: I tried converting the date to TIMESTAMP and also tried "CAST" but still the same error :(

Comment: Why the leading zeros on all the numbers?

Comment: Also, why the `.0` suffix on what are supposed to be integers?

Comment: as per you mentioned the scale for numeric it seems the default values always will be as  `0`  so you can avoid  scale for the  precision:) @user1103504

Comment: that should not be the problem as the values are getting inserted with or without leading zeroes and .0 suffix in sql developer.

Comment: How do you set null value for `MODIFIED_BY` field? Using `setNull` method or?

Comment: actually we are migrating from sql to oracle. The MODIFIED_BY field value is set to null only if it is 0. I'm handling it in my program. This works fine for the other tables too.

Comment: Please post part of your Java code where you populate values of (I suppose) PreparedStatement.

Comment: @  Miljen Mikic, added the code

Comment: Excellent, now just please add the content of list.get(6) element, i.e. the value you're using for populating field CREATED_DATE. I have some suspicions, this will confirm it.

Comment: @ Miljen Mikic, I din't get you. sorry :( coould you please explain what you are expecting to be posted ? the list.get(6) returns the TO_DATE('19102012130639','DDMMYYYYHH24MISS').

Comment: That's where the problem is, Java doesn't have a clue what's TO_DATE, it expects numeric value instead. However, BigMake already answered so I won't make duplicate post.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change your prepared statement in:

```
insert  into OPRS_ZONES(
  ZONE_ID,
  ZONE_CODE,
  ZONE_NAME,
  PLACE_ID,
  CORP_ID,
  CREATED_BY,
  CREATED_DATE,
  MODIFIED_BY,
  MODIFIED_DATE) 
values(?,?,?,?,?,?,
       TO_DATE(?,'DDMMYYYYHH24MISS'),
       ?,?)
```

And set only the actual CREATED_DATE as a string, that's to say make the getter in your collection object return "19102012130639" and not the whole TO_DATE syntax.

EDIT: assuming you have a String array containing all your values, and you use my edited statement version, this should work.

```
   String[] values = { "03.0", "FLORIDA", "FLORIDA", "05231.0", "01.0", "01.0",   "19102012130639", null, null };
   ps = conn.prepareStatement(query);
   int i = 1;
   foreach(String par : values) {
      ps.setObject(i, par);
      i++;
   }
   ps.execute();
```

Comment: Try to write a simple test unit, with the prepared statement and the .setObject() with values or at least add a trace of the actual values you set into your prepared statement. Remembre with prepared statements you don't need to escape string with ' and you don't need the TO_DATE () to be in the value, but just in the statement. So change the collection in order to contain only the date string.

Comment: is it that i need to convert that as a string ? the values after the changes according to your suggestion are as follows [03.0, 'FLORIDA', 'FLORIDA', 05231.0, 01.0, 01.0, 19102012130639, 00.0, NULL].. Do you want me to enclose in date value in quotes ?

Comment: The should be java types, as long as they're string or java primitive objects you should be right. How do you build up your collection ? Remember that ' escaping is done by the JDBC driver using prepared statements, so you don't need it.

Comment: I am generating a text file with values from the sql database for a particular table. I am using this text file to read the values and assigning them to the collection. I am also having a check for the dataType. The padding is taken care while generating the text file.

Answer (score 0):

I encountered the same problem, however, in my case, I had provided `sysdate` as an argument to the `DATE` field of the target table.

The solution was to change the value to a `java.sql.Timestamp`.